# Make na abstraction to kafka consumer using ktor and kotlin

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, ktor

I'm creating a abstraction for consumer and producer Kafka, to avoid duplicate code all the time. So i created a lib using kotlin and gradle, named "kafka-commons", and put the following code:
For Kafka producer:

```
fun producer(
    bootstrapServers: String,
    idempotence: Boolean,
    acks: Acks,
    retries: Int,
    requestPerConnection: Int,
    compression: Compression,
    linger: Int,
    batchSize: BatchSize
): KafkaProducer<String, Any> {
    val prop: HashMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
    prop[BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = bootstrapServers
    prop[KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringSerializer::class.java.name
    prop[VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringSerializer::class.java.name
    prop[ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG] = idempotence
    prop[ACKS_CONFIG] = acks.value
    prop[RETRIES_CONFIG] = retries
    prop[MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION] = requestPerConnection
    prop[COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG] = compression.value
    prop[LINGER_MS_CONFIG] = linger
    prop[BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG] = batchSize.value

    return KafkaProducer(prop)
}

suspend inline fun <reified K : Any, reified V : Any> KafkaProducer<K, V>.dispatch(record: ProducerRecord<K, V>) =
    suspendCoroutine<RecordMetadata> { continuation ->
        val callback = Callback { metadata, exception ->
            if (metadata == null) {
                continuation.resumeWithException(exception!!)
            } else {
                continuation.resume(metadata)
            }
        }
        this.send(record, callback)
    }
```

So, i created a default Command object with the following structure

```
data class Command(
    val id: UUID,
    val status: CommandStatus,
    val message: Any
)
```

id: create a unique ID
status: crete a message status (can be: Open /Processing / Closed / Error)
message: an object from http reques (for example: If have an Post

For example: if have a "insert user: POST" with body :

> {   "id": 1,   "name" : "John",   "lastName" : "Wick" }

so message will be this object, and so on.

And for create this command, i made this function:

```
suspend fun creatCommand(
    topicName: String,
    id: UUID,
    commandStatus: CommandStatus,
    request: Any,
    bootstrapServers: String,
    idempotence: Boolean,
    acks: Acks,
    retries: Int,
    requestPerConnection: Int,
    compression: Compression,
    linger: Int,
    batchSize: BatchSize
): Unit {
    val producer = producer(
        bootstrapServers,
        idempotence,
        acks,
        retries,
        requestPerConnection,
        compression,
        linger,
        batchSize)

    val command = toCommand(processStarted(id, commandStatus, request))
    val record = ProducerRecord<String, Any>(topicName, id.toString(), command)
    coroutineScope { launch { producer.dispatch(record) } }
}
```

So, I created other APIs and just call this function to create a producer that sends a command to kafka. Like:

```
fun Route.user(service: Service) =
    route("/api/access") {
        post("/test") {
            call.respond(service.command(call.receive())) 
            }
}

>>>>>> other class <<<<<<<<

classService () {
    fun command( all parameters) { creatCommand(all parameters)} 
}
```

Sor far so good. All works great.

Now my problemas begin. I'm trying to create a consumer. 
First i made this:

```
fun consumer(
    bootstrapServers: String,
    group: String,
    autoCommit: Boolean,
    offsetBehaviour: OffsetBehaviour,
    pollMax: Int
): KafkaConsumer<String, Any> {
    val prop: HashMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
    prop[BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = bootstrapServers
    prop[KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringDeserializer::class.java.name
    prop[VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringDeserializer::class.java.name
    prop[GROUP_ID_CONFIG] = group
    prop[AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG] = offsetBehaviour
    prop[ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG] = autoCommit
    prop[MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG] = pollMax

    return KafkaConsumer(prop)
}
```

And after:

```
fun<T> recordingCommand(
    command: Class<T>,
    topic: String,
    bootstrapServers: String,
    group: String,
    autoCommit: Boolean,
    offsetBehaviour: OffsetBehaviour,
    pollMax: Int
) {
    val consumer = consumer(bootstrapServers, group, autoCommit, offsetBehaviour, pollMax)
    consumer.subscribe(mutableListOf(topic))
    while (true) {
        val records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100))
        for (record in records) {
            val om = ObjectMaper
            om.readvalue(record.value(), command::class.java)

            >>>> I GOT LOST HERE <<<<<<

        }
    }
}
```

What i need: creating a abstract consumer that record all data inside a Command.message() (only the message) in a database.

For example, i need to record the user above (id 1, john wick ) into a postgresql database.
So if i had a service with insert method, i can call it, passing insertmethod like:

```
service.insert(recordingCommand(all parameters)).
```

Anyone can help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are having issues with JSON mapping into objects

```
   val mapper = ObjectMaper
   while (true) {
        val records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100))
        for (record in records) {
            val cmd = mapper.readvalue(record.value(), command::class.java)
            // do things with cmd
        }
    }
```

Note: Kafka has its own JSON to POJO deserializer, and if you want to send data to a database, Kafka Connect is generally more fault-tolerant than your simple consume loop.